# Setting the value of an image using a String

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have a string, `imgchng`, and twenty images, `image1, image2, image3,`etc.

The value of imgchng is always the name of one of the images.

How would I set the value of the the current image that `imgchng` is referring to?

For instance, the user sets the value of `imgchng` as `image12`. How would I tell `image12`'s source to change?

`imgchng.Source = (source goes here);` doesn't work, because that would set the property of the string, not the image.

I know how to set the source of the image, just not how to set the source of whatever image the string is referring to.

My intention is to avoid a humongous `if` statement that would be over 1000 lines long, like the example one below:

```
        if (textBlock2.Text == "First User Selection")
        {
            if (imgchng == "image1")
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/FirstImg.png"));
                image1.Source = bmp;
            }
            else if (imgchng == "image2")
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/FirstImg.png"));
                image2.Source = bmp;
            }
            //Continue this for all 20 images
        }
        else if (textBlock2.Text == "Second User Selection")
        {
            if (imgchng == "image1")
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/SecondImg.png"));
                image1.Source = bmp;
            }
            else if (imgchng == "image2")
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/SecondImg.png"));
                image2.Source = bmp;
            }
            //Continue this for all 20 images
        }
        else if (textBlock2.Text == "Third User Selection")
        {
            if (imgchng == "image1")
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/ThirdImg.png"));
                image1.Source = bmp;
            }
            else if (imgchng == "image2")
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/ThirdImg.png"));
                image2.Source = bmp;
            }
            //Continue this for all 20 images
        }
        else if (textBlock2.Text == "Fourth User Selection")
        {
            if (imgchng == "image1")
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/FourthImg.png"));
                image1.Source = bmp;
            }
            else if (imgchng == "image2")
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/FourthImg.png"));
                image2.Source = bmp;
            }
            //Continue this for all 20 images
        }
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is, as @ctacke said, given the string 'image1', how do I get the instance of the control named 'image1'?

Comment: what do you mean by `image12`'s  source.. isn't that the name of the image itself..?

Comment: The source of `image12` is a small 50*50 image. I know how to set the background of the `image`, just not how to decide which `image` to change without using a humongous `if` statement.

Comment: So is the question here "Given the string 'image1', how do I get the instance of the control named 'image1'?"

Comment: @ctacke: Yeah, that's basically what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a BitmapImage array of 20 images. Bind that to the UI. Take the user selection as an integer. Access the image from array using index (obviously user input -1).Change the source of that image. Does this resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes, that solves it. Sort of tedious to do all of the             `BitmapImage img10 = new BitmapImage();`s (I had to do this on 5 different XAML pages), but it's still a shorter solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To set the source of the image you have to do the following.

```
BitmapImage bmp=new BitmapImage(new Uri("your image name will go here"));
image.Source=bmp;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, what I want to do is detect which `image` to change based on the value of `imgchng`.For instance, if the value of `ingchng` is `"image1"`, then I want to change the value of `image1`. If the value of `imgchng` is `"image19"`, then I want to change the background of `image19`. I know how to set the background of the `image`- just not how to decide which image to change without using a humongous `if` statement.